# AudioPlaybackCaptureConfiguration not working in Android BOX (Using HDMI)

Tags: android, actions-on-google, hdmi, audio-capture

I am using google Audio Playback Capture API in ANDROID API Level 29 and its working fine on Android mobile devices i get easily internal audio from the devices but when i test it on the Android TV Box , Basically this app is TV box app where i have to capture internal audio. My Android TV Box connected with HDMI cable but i didn't receive any sound i am using Attributes : USAGE_MEDIA,USAGE_UNKNOWN and USAGE_GAME
they are all working fine in mobile app but not when i run on Android Box. I have done everything from my side now i just need help regarding getting audio from HDMI.
Thanks

```
                val config = AudioPlaybackCaptureConfiguration.Builder(AudioCaptureService.mediaProjection!!)
                    .addMatchingUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                    .addMatchingUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_UNKNOWN)
                    .addMatchingUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
                    .build()


            val audioFormat = AudioFormat.Builder()
                    .setEncoding(AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)
                    .setSampleRate(buffer.sampleRate)
                        .setChannelMask(AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO)
                    .build()

            val record = AudioRecord.Builder()
                    .setAudioFormat(audioFormat)
                    .setAudioPlaybackCaptureConfig(config)
                    .setBufferSizeInBytes(buffer.size)
                    .build()
```